# setting a bash variable in awk

Tags: bash, awk, environment-variables

I have

```
grep 5980 list.txt > temp; awk '{ print $4}' temp
```

but instead of just printing the results I would like to set it to an environment variable.

I'm kind of new to bash and awk so an explanation would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

```
export variable=$(grep 5980 list.txt > temp; awk '{ print $4}' temp)
```

Comment: And, without a temp file: `export variable=$(awk '/5980/ {print $4}' list.txt)`

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to save the output in temp,you can use the below command:

```
export variable=$(awk '/5980/{print $4}' list.txt)
```